# How to using Akka Futures asynchronously in Java

Tags: java, akka

I'm making a call in a Java service layer that looks like this;

```
Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(myActor, message, timeout);

Response res = (Response) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
```

I've read the Akka documentation and realize blocking like this is not recommended. I need to return the response object to the calling method. Is it possible do this asynchronously with Akka from my Java service? I tried to do this using the `future.onSuccess` method however the `onSuccess` method does not allow a return value so I can't return the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The akka way of passing data between threads, which is essentially what you are doing by blocking above is to compose futures or to send a message to an Actor.

The following example has been taken from the [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.5/java/futures.html).

```
final ExecutionContext ec = system.dispatcher();

Future<String> f1 = future(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() {
        return "Hello" + "World";
    }
}, ec);

Future<Integer> f2 = f1.map(new Mapper<String, Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(String s) {
        return s.length();
    }
}, ec);

f2.onSuccess(new PrintResult<Integer>(), system.dispatcher());
```

Notice that in this example data is being 'returned', or more precisely it is being handed off to another unit of work without a thread having to block and wait for a result.

This is why onSuccess returns void, it is to be used at the end of a chain of composed futures.  If it was to return a value, it would be like map and it would return another Future.  Which would leave you with the same requirement of blocking.

Thus to answer your question, no.  There is no way to 'return' a value from an asynchronous future without blocking.  Instead you should review why you need Response to be returned like that, and see if instead you can move the handling of Response into either onSuccess or map.  A minor alternative is to return Future[Response] and let the caller worry about chaining the futures.  The case that you have hit usually happens when mixing paradigms, and it is best avoided.

Comment: the call which blocks is initiated when a user hits a service on my website. I block on the thread because i want the response to the request to contain some data to update the UI. How would you recommend i do this?

Comment: @cdugga GUI code is usually designed around continuations/callbacks anyway, so that part should be straight forward.  The trick is usually the network part; if the network code is designed to be async (using futures and nio under the hood) then bingo.  Otherwise you have no choice, you have to block and that is what I was referring to about mixing paradigms.  Most Java network code is designed around the old school hold one thread and block model, and when that type of code is mixed with Akka then one has to block somewhere.  Just try to minimise it and keep it contained to one or two places.

Comment: @cdugga when I am working with clients who have this type of code, and the code base is too large to shift over to a totally async solution in one go then I tend to start at the lowest layer and start changing DAOs etc from returning DTO to Future[DTO].  When this interface crosses to the non-async realm there is a block.  Over time I push it higher and higher until it is at the network code, and then the final step is to swap out the network library for an async one.

Comment: @cdugga the other possibility that one often hits is where a db or webservice call is using a blocking api; in that case a Future or Actor can be used to wrap that api and it can be assigned a single thread away from Akka's global thread pool.  Thus making the blocking API appear to be non-blocking to Akka, and avoids polution of the global thread pool that can cause eratic performance of otherwise fast futures and at an extreme Akka can lock up.