# How to return actor received message to java?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I am new to akka , I am using akka as a RPC service . I know akka is more than that , but this is where I started.

There is an `UserServiceActor` that reports how many users in the service :

```
@Inject
private UserService userService;

@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
  if (message instanceof CountReq) {
    long count = userService.getUserCount();
    getSender().tell(new CountRes(count) , getSelf());
  }
  else {
    unhandled(message);
  }
}
```

This `UserServiceActor` runs on remote machine. And in the local machine , there is another `LocalActor` that negotiates with the remote actor.

```
if (message instanceof CountReq) {
  remote.tell(message, getSelf());
}
if (message instanceof CountRes) {
  getSender().tell(message, getSelf());
} else {
  unhandled(message);
}
```

Follow this example : [An Akka actors 'ask' example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-akka-actors-ask-examples-future-await-timeout-result)

I write a client :

```
@Inject
private ActorRef localActor;

public long getUserCount() {
  Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(localActor, new CountReq(), 10000);
  try {
    Object res = Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
    logger.info("res = {}" , res);
    return (Long) res;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

The code example in [1](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-akka-actors-ask-examples-future-await-timeout-result) just returns a string to the sender , so the non-actor world can get the result.

But in my situation , the client sends `CountReq` to the localActor , and actor send the `CountReq` to remote server . and remote server returns `CountRes` . At that time , the sender becomes the remote `UserServiceActor` , not the non-actor client .

Some page suggests reading [Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html) , but I still cannot find how to accomplish this ?

Is there any java code example or sample project about such RPC-style actor , and pass the result to the non-actor world ?

Environment : 2 SpringBoot apps  , akka-actor_2.11 version 2.3.11

Thanks.

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate question, your answer is correct, but keep in mind that if you wanted to remain reactive instead of waiting for the future the answer to this question shows how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408311/how-to-using-akka-futures-asynchronously-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by this way :

```
private ActorRef caller = null;

inside onReceive() :
if (message instanceof CountReq) {
  this.caller = getSender();
  remote.tell(message, getSelf());
}
if (message instanceof CountRes) {
  caller.tell(message , getSelf());
}
```

I don't know if it the '**standard**' way , but at least it works.

Any better solutions are welcome !